# How to get a centred rolling mean?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the rolling mean of data taken on successive days. If I just use dataframe.rolling(7) the mean is from the previous week.  Instead I would like day to be at the centre of the window the mean is computed over not right at the end.  Is there an easy/fast way to get such a centred rolling mean of a pandas Series?

Comment: have you checked df.rolling(7, win_type='triang').sum()
there are other win_type options as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```py
df.rolling(7, center=True).mean()
```

The rolling mean can be centered by setting the `center` argument to `True`.

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe5ZU.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
df.shift(-4).rolling(7).mean()
```

Should do the trick.